# Execute asynchronous task triggered by web request in ASP.NET MVC on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asynchronous, message-queue

Given a REST API implemented in ASP.NET MVC 4 that:

- Triggers communication with an external API on some requests
- Performs this communication asynchronously to ensure responsive endpoints
- Retries the external communication of the external API is unavailable
- Ensure that the communication does occur

and has the following additional details:

- Deployed on Azure
- Needs to work as a Web Site and execute the background request locally
- Needs to work as a cloud app and execute the background request locally or scaled externally

what are the best practices / options for executing asynchronous tasks triggered by web requests in ASP.NET MVC 4 on Azure?

Comment: I don't fully understand your requirements. Why not use Storage Queues or Service Bus Queues for this with a background process processing those requests?

Comment: Storage Queues and Service Bus Queues will both work. However, Storage Queues require polling. We are currently doing it with Service Bus Queues but those require running a background thread to listen on the queue. It works but does anyone know a better pattern for solving this problem?